# Does the primarch have to die on Palaven?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I got to Palaven I was told that the Primarch was dead.  Is this an irreversible part of the story, or did he die because I decided to do two other missions first?  If I had gone to Palaven right away, would he have survived?

Comment: Yes he does. It was sad that he died though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this mission right away and he was still dead.

It is part of the story to meet the new Primarch, who is just learning of his responsibilities and grows with Shepard to meet his new role.